# Inserting a variable in MongoDB specifying _id field

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to insert a variable, say,

```
a = {1:2,3:4}
```

into my database with a particular id "56". It is very clear from the docs that I can do the following:

```
db.testcol.insert({"_id": "56", 1:2, 3:4})
```

However, I cannot figure out any way to insert "a" itself, specifying an id. In other words, I want to do something like this

```
db.testcol.insert(a, "_id"="56")
```

but it does not work. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Why not add the `_id` key to `a`?

Comment: It works! I knew the solution must be simple, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert only accepts a final document or an array of documents, and an optional object which contains additional options for the collection.

```
db.collection.insert(
   <document or array of documents>,
   { // options
     writeConcern: <document>,
     ordered: <boolean>
   }
)
```

You may want to add the _id to the document in advance, but separated from document's creation:

```
a = {1:2,3:4}
```

**Using dot notation:**

```
a._id = 56;
```

**Using square bracket notation:**

```
a['_id'] = 56;
```

Then, the insert:

```
db.testcol.insert(a);
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : 56,
    "1" : 2,
    "3" : 4
}
```

By the way, this is actually how you would add a key-value pair to an object in JavaScript.

Comment: @Alekz112, I guess you want to separate the creation of the document from defining its _id. Please look at the edit.

Comment: Both yes and no. Basically, I was wondering about how to explicitly specify the _id at the moment of inserting the document (variable). So simply adding the _id to variable also fits my needs.